# Code blocks boolean error

Tags: c++

I want to do Boolean Equations like 5<7 would be true and 7<5 will be false like that.

As the code I execute it asks for value of A and I put a value and enter but then he don't ask for value of b .. and sum comes up a random number..

Now after i again launch it I type 1 in a value then it is asking for value of b ,I type 2 but still Answer is showing like A-B

```
int main() {   
    bool a;
    bool b;

    cout << "enter value for a" << endl;
    cin>>a;
    cout << "enter value for a" << endl;
    cin >> b;
    bool e = a < b;
    cout << "sum is" << e;
    return 0;
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Please always use `code block` for posting your code examples, don't just screenshot your text editor and paste image here.

Comment: `bool` won't take a value like 5 or 7, so your `a` and `b` won't have the values you expect in them.

Comment: A side note: Any statement after `return` won't be executed.

Comment: bool only accepts two values, either `0`(false) or non-zero which is evaluated into `1`(true). To add integer numbers, you may use `int` keyword, otherwise, use `double` or `float` keywords for decimal numbers. In your case you must declare `a` and `b` as integer types. Your `e` is fine but your last output should be `std::cout << "Condition: " << e;`. Since you are not asking for their summation but condition if a is less than b, then e will be true else false.

Comment: bool will not take value like 5 or 7 why??

Comment: But the operation will be like this 5<7 true i think so..

Comment: @VG Thanks man I understand That Like cout<<" a<b"<< e; .. like this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bool` only accepts two conditions, either 0 which is false or non-zero which is evaluated into 1 (true). To add integer numbers, you shall use the keyword `int`, for decimal numbers do use `double` or `float`.

In your case, you must declare `a` and `b` as integer types instead of `bool`. Your boolean variable `e` is fine which receives the condition of whether or not the variable `a` is less than the variable `b`. Your last `std::cout` should not ask for their summation since `e` was not used to sum them up but get the condition from `a < b`.

```
#include  <iostream>

int main() {
  int a;
  int b;

  std::cout << "enter value for a " << std::endl;
  std::cin >> a;
  std::cout << "enter value for b " << std::endl;
  std::cin >> b;

  bool e = a < b;
  std::cout << "a < b is: " << e << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: write i understand it :)

Comment: Walaikum -O-ASSALAM , yup it helps me alot. i have many questions to ask also, I will tag u in My Questions :) @V G

Comment: Haha no problem, do it whenever applicable. I will answer if I'm eligible.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want this:

```
#include  <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int a;   // int instead of bool
  int b;   // int instead of bool

  cout << "enter value for a " << endl;
  cin >> a;
  cout << "enter value for b " << endl;
  cin >> b;

  bool e = a < b;
  cout << "a < b is " << e << endl;  // prints 1 for true and 0 for false
  return 0;
  // getch();   // useless because it will never be executed after return 0;
}
```

Look at the comments for an explanation.

Comment: @PaulR question is a bit unclear, but I added a second solution

Comment: @PaulR yes, you are probably right, I edited the answer

Comment: thanks Guys, Sorry Em new in programming And Also to this website :) ignore my Mistakes

Comment: How did u do it?? I can't still find out how everything i write was good right??

Comment: and why that // int instead of bool??? we are going to perform boolean operation so It will be bool.. and getch , and So 5<7 i get answer 1 which is true so can't there be a code instead of 1 there should be written true??

Comment: @AHMEDALI because in the question it was `bool a ;`. He wants the user to enter `int`s for example `4` and `5` and you cannot have `int`s in a `bool`.